# How to call a js function on another webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i want to call a javascript function on another webpage. So far, my solution is to create a page with an iframe containing the target page.

```
<a onclick="func1()">Call</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func1() 
        {
            document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.some_function();
        }
    </script>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.webpage.com">
```

Problem is, that this solution only works when both pages have the same domain. Otherwise, i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://my_webpage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://not_my_webpage.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I have googled for hours, but i have only found that i need to use

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```

After using it, i get this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://my_webpage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://not_my_webpage.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "http://my_webpage.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

I guess that i need to use it on both pages, but the page in iframe isn't mine and i don't have acces to it. Any ideas? Thanx.

Comment: It is not possible, this security mechanism was added to exactly prevent this by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't do it. Imagine if this kind of things were possible... it would be an enormous security flaw. That's because you can't access a frame that has another origin, the browser automatically blocks every script that tries to access some window that hasn't the same origin.

Comment: Well, there's [CORS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which can allow this (but requires the external server to allow it, not the originating service/web-page).

Comment: Yeah I know, but find me some site that uses it... one in one billion, maybe. Since that the OP has no control on the foreign page he can't do anything.

Comment: Alternatively, you can send messages between pages on different domains using [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).